# How to use ResultReceiver in AIDL

Tags: android, aidl

I'd like to declare an asynchronous service API in AIDL using ResultReceiver instead of creating my own callback interface.

But when I try to import android.os.ResultReceiver, it doesn't know that ResultReceiver is parcelable.  Is there a trick?

Example:

```
import android.os.ResultReceiver;

interface IPrimeService {
    int computePrimes(in int number, in ResultReceiver resultReceiver);
}
```

Results in (Android 2.2):

```
IPrimeService.aidl:3: couldn't find import for class android.os.ResultReceiver
```

It seems if I create ResultReceiver.aidl in src/android/os within my project like:

```
package android.os;

parcelable ResultReceiver;
```

it works, but that seems like such a hack. Is there a better way?

Thanks, Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue.. I edited /platform/android-<#>/framework.aidl to include the line

parceable android.os.ResultReceiver;

and then it works

credit: http://amdroid.ampache.org/?p=38